# Is it possible to install Ubuntu onto a DVD?

Tags: 11.10, installation, dvd

Is it possible to install Ubuntu 11.10 onto a DVD as a full working version, which treats the DVD as the hard drive (like you can with a [USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80761/install-run-usb-11-04-and-keep-changes))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not **install** ubuntu in a dvd like a USB storage device. But there is an alternative. You can make a live dvd from your harddisk ubuntu installation. Unlike USB, *you can not store files after working in the dvd*. You have to store files in your hard drive.